# Combining wave plates?

Tags: electromagnetism, polarization

In the context of classical electromagnetism, is it always possible to reproduce the action of a large number of half-wave plates and quarter wave-plates with that of a single half-wave plate and a single quarter wave-plate. If so please can you explain why this is the case and if not why not.

Comment: A question that has a yes/no answer is not a very good question for this forum. There is a minimum character count. In this case the answer is "yes". But you can't post that as an answer. Would you like to try to make the question a little broader / more specific?